Year fixed effects vs dropping one year dummy
I am running regressions with year fixed effects, but one of my covariates is age, which is perfectly collinear with year. I’ve noticed that some papers include year dummies but drop one year to allow age to appear in the results. Could you explain the pros and cons of this approach? Is there a clear advantage to either approach, or is one generally considered better?
Thanks!

Could the reason for dropping one year dummy be to avoid the dummy variable trap?

If you have year entered as a categorical variable, then one year must be dropped. This is not because of having age in the model and is true of any categorical variable (technically, there are some codings of categorical variables that get around this, but I don't want to get into that here; I think it would just complicate things).
If age is also treated categorically, then one age will also have to be dropped.
Generally, I favor treating variables such as age and year as continuous variables. This saves degrees of freedom, and lets you look at curvilinear effects (if you want) using splines (of course, splines use up df).
Dropping one level of either variable will not cure colinearity; more precisely, it will make the colinearity less than perfect, so the model may not "blow up" and you may get estimates out. But these will suffer from the usual problems of colinearity, such as extreme sensitivity to the initial data and high variances on the parameter estimates.
